# WinSCP SFTP - .tmp The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to upload file using following code but getting error below.

Some notes: I'm using Windows 7. Using CrushFTP SFTP server, able to connect with using FileZilla and WinSCP client, but through code its being nightmare.

Error/exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp0D64.036B20B7.tmp' because it
>   is being used by another process.

My code to connect is below

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions 
{ 
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp, 
    HostName = "127.0.0.1", //hostname e.g. IP: 192.54.23.32, or mysftpsite.com 
    UserName = "xxxxxx", 
    Password = "yyyyyy", 
    PortNumber = zzzzz, //some number 
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024 ::::04:85:3b:7a::::::::" 
}; 

using (Session session = new Session()) 
{ 
    session.Open(sessionOptions); //Attempts to connect to your sFtp site 
    //Get Ftp File 
    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions(); 
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary; //The Transfer Mode - 
    // Automatic, Binary, or Ascii 
    transferOptions.FilePermissions = null; //Permissions applied to remote files; 
    //null for default permissions. Can set user, 
    //Group, or other Read/Write/Execute permissions. 
    transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = false; //Set last write time of 
    //destination file to that of source file - basically change the timestamp 
    //to match destination and source files. 
    transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off; 

    TransferOperationResult transferResult; 
    //the parameter list is: local Path, Remote Path, Delete source file?, transfer Options 
    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"C:\Adnan\a.txt", "/", false, transferOptions); 
    //Throw on any error 
    transferResult.Check(); 
    //Log information and break out if necessary 
}
```

Comment: Can you include a call stack or even better a debug log ([`Session.DebugLogPath`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session))?

Comment: debug log.. last few lines                                                                                                                . 2015-01-20 09:52:26.317 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-01-20 09:52:26.317 Looking up host "127.0.0.11"
. 2015-01-20 09:52:26.317 Connecting to 127.0.0.11 port 54545
. 2015-01-20 09:52:27.318 Failed to connect to 127.0.0.11: Network error: Connection refused
. 2015-01-20 09:52:27.318 Using non-standard protocol or port, tunnel or proxy, will not knock FTP port.

Comment: This is not a debug log. It's session log (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Did you ever figure out what the problem was here. I am having the same difficulty...

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered this exception. For me, it was generated on the call to `session.Open(...)`.

However, this is an internal exception that is both generated and caught by the WinSCP assembly. I only noticed it because I had configured Visual Studio to stop on every exception thrown. If I turn this setting off (or continue past this and some additional internal IOExceptions), the SFTP connection opens correctly.